# Inject variable with custom parameter without creating 2 guice helper interfaces?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm using guice to dynamically inject classes in my constructors. For example:

```
@Inject
public PublisherFrame(EventBus eventBus, MyPublisherService publishService)
```

And in my guice module:

```
bind(EventBus.class).in(Singleton.class);
bind(MyPublisherService.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

Works without problems.

The problem starts when i create a object which has a parameter which is constructed in java code:

```
public LoginController(EventBus eventBus, MyPublisherService publisherService, LoginDialog dlg)
```

Here LoginDialog is a java class which java codes create. To solve this i use @assist and:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(ILoginController.class, LoginController.class).build(GuiceLoginControllerFactory.class));
```

Works also nicely. But now i have to create 2 extra java files:

- a new interface for LoginController: ILoginController, which doesn't do anything except help guice.
- another interface for guice: GuiceLoginControllerFactory

Is there an easier way to inject a variable which has a custom parameter in the constructor? (without creating 2 extra "guice" helper files)

Comment: How about a `@Provider` for that third parameter? If that doesn't work how about a setter method for that field?

Comment: Cheers condit, didn't think of that one, i'm going to also take a look at that one soon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't actually need the additional interface for the class itself (see below). Furthermore, I generally create my factory as a nested interface of the class it creates:

```
public class LoginController {
  public interface Factory {
    LoginController create(LoginDialog dlg);
  }

  @Inject public LoginController(
      EventBus eventBus,
      MyPublisherService publisherService,
      @Assisted LoginDialog dlg) { /* ... */ }
}

// in your module
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(LoginController.Factory.class));
```

You don't need to call `FactoryModuleBuilder.implement` unless you want your Factory's factory method's return type to be an interface rather than a concrete class--then Guice won't know what kind of concrete type to construct without your help. In the example below, you couldn't ask FactoryModuleBuilder to simply implement `LoginService.Factory` for you, as it would have no idea which concrete LoginService implementor to instantiate:

```
interface LoginService {
  interface Factory {
    LoginService create(NetConnection connection);
  }
  boolean login(String username, String password);
}

class SimpleLoginService implements LoginService {
  @Inject SimpleLoginService(@Assisted NetConnection connection) { /* ... */ }
}

class SecuredLoginService implements LoginService {
  @Inject SecuredLoginService(
      EncryptionService encryptionService,
      @Assisted NetConnection connection) { /* ... */ }
}

// in your module: implements LoginService.Factory
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
    .implement(LoginService.class, SimpleLoginService.class)
    .build(LoginService.Factory.class));
// this one implements @Secured LoginService.Factory
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
    .implement(LoginService.class, SecuredLoginService.class)
    .build(Key.get(LoginService.Factory.class, Secured.class));
```

Barring that, *condit*'s idea of creating a setter method isn't bad, though that does mean that you are constructing your class in a partially-initialized state.

Comment: Thank you Jeff for the reply and you thoughts on the subject. It looks like a good idea, i'm currently not able to test it directly, but i will soon. Thumbs up!